# Missing operand in batch file loop

Tags: batch-file, while-loop, operand

I was pretty certain that this should work, but I can't see what the issue is that's causing the missing operand.  The loop seems to be working fine, but for some reason the _num variable isn't incrementing as it should.
It seems that set /a isn't working as expected here.

```
@echo off

cls
cd \
cd /d D:\
set /a _num1=1
set /a _num=1
:LOOP 
if exist D:\%_num%.zip (
    set /a "%_num%+=%_num1%"
    goto LOOP
)

echo "%_num%.zip"
pause
exit
@echo on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if exist "D:\%_num%.zip" (
    set /a _num+=1
    goto LOOP
)
```

Comment: +1, The minimum change required to get OP's code to work is `set /a "_num+=%_num1%"`. I would probably use `set /a "_num+=_num1"`

Comment: Endoro, exactly what I was trying to achieve and reducing the amount of code I had.  I don't know how many times that I have to relearn this lesson with variables in CMD for it to stick.

dbenham, you're right, however, I liked Endoro's thinking.